Error Running MoviePy in a Frozen Python Application with cx_Freeze
I'm encountering a persistent issue when trying to run a Python application that uses moviepy, which has been frozen using cx_Freeze. The application throws an error related to ffmpeg when I attempt to run the frozen executable, despite setting the ffmpeg path correctly in development and ensuring ffmpeg is included in the build.
Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\_startup__.py", line 141, in run
  module_init.run(name + "__main__")
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.py", line 25, in run
  exec(code, main_globals)
File "merger.py", line 8, in <module>
  from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 36, in <module>
  from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
  from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
  from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioClip
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 7, in <module>
  from moviepy.audio.io.ffmpeg_audiowriter import ffmpeg_audiowrite
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 7, in <module>
  from moviepy.config import get_setting
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\moviepy\config.py", line 36, in <module>
  FFMPEG_BINARY = get_exe()
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py", line 173, in get_exe
  return imageio_ffmpeg.get_ffmpeg_exe()
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\_utils.py", line 28, in get_ffmpeg_exe
  exe = _get_ffmpeg_exe()
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg_utils.py", line 44, in _get_ffmpeg_exe
  exe = os.path.join(_get_bin_dir(),
  FNAME_PER_PLATFORM.get(plat, ""))
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg_utils.py", line 69, in _get_bin_dir
  ref = importlib.resources.files("imageio_ffmpeg.binaries") / "__init__.py"
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\resources.py", line 147, in files
  return _common.from_package(_get_package(package))
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib_common.py", line 14, in from_package
  return fallback_resources(package.__spec__)
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib_common.py", line 18, in fallback_resources
  package_directory = pathlib.Path(spec.origin).parent
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1082, in __new__
  self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 707, in _from_parts
  drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
File "C:\***\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 691, in _parse_args
  a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

This error occurs specifically when I'm trying to use MoviePy's VideoFileClip function.
Details:
Python Version: 3.9
moviepy Version: Latest from GitHub
cx_Freeze Version: 7.1.1
OS: Windows 11
I have included ffmpeg in the cx_Freeze build using the include_files option and set the IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE environment variable both in development and in the frozen setup.
Code Snippet:
import os
import sys
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def configure_ffmpeg():
    ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'ffmpeg', 'bin', 'ffmpeg.exe')
    if not os.path.exists(ffmpeg_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"ffmpeg executable not found at {ffmpeg_path}")
    os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = ffmpeg_path

configure_ffmpeg()
clip = VideoFileClip('path_to_video.mp4')

Setup.py Configuration:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "moviepy", "idna"],
    "include_files": [('C:/ffmpeg/bin', ffmpeg/bin')]}

setup(
    name="MyApp",
    version="0.1",
    description="My MoviePy application",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("script.py")])

I'm not sure why the executable can't find or utilize ffmpeg even though the path seems to be set correctly and works outside of the frozen environment. How can I resolve this error to ensure ffmpeg works correctly in a frozen cx_Freeze environment?
The application throws an error related to ffmpeg when I attempt to run the frozen executable, despite setting the ffmpeg path correctly in development and ensuring ffmpeg is included in the build.

I think the problem comes from Moviepy. When I used ffmpeg directly, the issue was resolved.
